# Has $\pi$ been represented as a radical expression of a prime number?

Tags: number-theory

I've searched other resources but can't find the answer. My question is whether $\pi$ can be expressed as some radical root of a prime number.

Whether this is possible or not seems interesting to me in a way that is hard to explain. I'm a seasoned programmer with a only a recent interest in abstract algebra, so pardon my ignorance if this question is trivial or absurd in some way.

Comment: Possibly this got downvoted because it seems "trivial or absurd" to someone who knows that $\pi$ is transcendental (and knows what that means). But for someone just learning about algebraic and transcendental numbers--or who is not even aware of such terms--here is an opportunity to see a concrete application of the definitions.

Comment: @David K - Thank you. This is my first post at math.stackexchange.com. Pure math is becoming a hobby of mine, and I have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this is not the case because $\pi$ is not an [algebraic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_number) number.

If $\pi=\sqrt[N]{p}$ for $N\in\mathbb{N}$ and $p$ prime then
$$\pi^N=p\Rightarrow \pi^N-p=0$$
and so $\pi$ is a root of the polynomial $x^N-p$. This can't be the case as $\pi$ is not the root of any polynomial with rational coefficients.

Please see the links for more.

The proof that $\pi$ is not algebraic (but transcendental) is mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindemann%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem).

Comment: Oh, I see now :) But I'm not so sure that it answers the question at hand, so you'll have to give some more details I think.

Comment: Well perhaps the OP might explain what "radical expression of a prime number" is because if he means $\pi=\sqrt[N]{p}$ or similar for some $N\in \mathbb{N}$ and prime $p$ this is all he needs and does answer the question.

Comment: @Jp McCarthy "if he means π=p‾√N or similar for some N∈ℕ and prime p", this is exactly what I meant

Comment: Well then this answers your question. Let me elaborate.

Comment: Minor correction: "rational coefficients".

Comment: @DavidK yes thank you.